# is it possible to trim the table output for a specific job?

Tags: sql-server, jobs, scripting, logs, troubleshooting

I have a [routine to save the logins and apply them on a different server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/918992/how-to-transfer-logins-and-passwords-between-instances-of-sql-server) , and I run this routine from a job that I have scheduled to run everyday.

On that `job` I have specified these 3 things:

1. Log to table
2. Append output to existing entry in table
3. Include step output in history

as can be seen on the picture below:

[image]

I am happy with that, however, I was wondering if there is a way to trim the table output because when I open it I see records from over 4 months ago, which are no longer relevant now, as shown on the picture below:

when I click `View`:

[image]

I get:

[image]

and the table has over 61 thousand lines.

Every time the job runs it adds about 600 new lines to the bottom of the table.

Can I keep the last let's say 10 thousand lines only,getting rid of the older lines?

Comment: the `commandlog cleanup` gets rid of the following entries: `select * FROM master.[dbo].[CommandLog] WHERE StartTime < DATEADD(dd,-30,GETDATE())`. I would then need to know what table inside the `msdb` database where I can find the entries I want to delete from `my view table` on that job.

Comment: This may be overkill, but still useful: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5969/manage-sql-server-agent-history-more-effectively/ ... you could of course use the same kind of logic against any table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a partial solution - as I could not find out how to just trim the table log.

using [sp_purge_jobhistory](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/235432/22336)

```
DECLARE @DAY DATETIME = DATEADD( dd,-30,getdate())
exec msdb.dbo.sp_purge_jobhistory   
   @job_name = 'DBA - Save the JOBS and LOGINS'
 , @oldest_date = @DAY
```

that trims the jobhistory not the table log

[image]

what is supposed to trim that table log is [sp_delete_jobsteplog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-delete-jobsteplog-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

this is suppose to delete all records in that table - and it does:

```
DECLARE @DAY DATETIME = DATEADD( dd,-30,getdate())
PRINT @DAY
exec msdb.dbo.sp_delete_jobsteplog 
   @job_name = 'DBA - Save the JOBS and LOGINS',
   @step_name = 'SAVE THE LOGINS'
```

this is the original situation:

[image]

[sp_help_jobsteplog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-help-jobsteplog-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) shows who is actually the log table and where it lives and how big it is

```
exec msdb.dbo.sp_help_jobsteplog
   @job_name = 'DBA - Save the JOBS and LOGINS',
   @step_name = 'SAVE THE JOBS'
```

[image]

this does not work as I would expect it to:

```
DECLARE @DAY DATETIME = DATEADD( dd,-30,getdate())
PRINT @DAY
exec msdb.dbo.sp_delete_jobsteplog 
   @job_name = 'DBA - Save the JOBS and LOGINS',
   @step_name = 'SAVE THE JOBS',
   @older_than = @day,
   @larger_than = 52428800
```

[image]

this does delete `all records` - not exactly what I wanted:

```
exec msdb.dbo.sp_delete_jobsteplog 
   @job_name = 'DBA - Save the JOBS and LOGINS',
   @step_name = 'SAVE THE JOBS',
   --@older_than = @day,
   @larger_than = 52428800
```

[image]

I think I found out why [Parameter in sp_delete_jobsteplog don’t work](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/parameter-in-sp_delete_jobsteplog-dont-work)

Here is how I understand the function of `sp_delete_jobsteplog`.

The `sysjobstepslogs` table has one row for each job/step that you are logging. Every time the job runs, it concatenates the new log to the end of the “log” column for that step. Multiple logs are all stored as one concatenated `VARCHAR(MAX)`.

When you run `sp_delete_jobsteplog` with the `@older_than parameter`, it does not parse through the “log” column and remove entries older than you want, as you might expect. What it does is looks at the “date_modified” column and deletes the entire row if that date is older than `@older_than`. So if the job runs once per hour and you want to delete everything older than 3 days, it will never delete anything because the “date_modified” will always be less than an hour old.

Here is the code from inside `sp_delete_jobsteplog` (SQL Server 2012 SP3).

```
DELETE FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobstepslogs
 WHERE (step_uid IN (SELECT DISTINCT step_uid 
        FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps js, msdb.dbo.sysjobs_view jv
        WHERE (  @job_id = jv.job_id )
          AND (js.job_id = jv.job_id )
          AND ((@step_id IS NULL) OR (@step_id = step_id)))) 
  AND ((@older_than IS NULL) OR (date_modified < @older_than))
  AND ((@larger_than IS NULL) OR (log_size > @larger_than))
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

The `CommandLog` cleanup is from Ola Hallengren's Maintenance Solution, so doesn't affect msdb history directly.

Use [`sp_purge_jobhistory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-purge-jobhistory-transact-sql), like so:

```
sp_purge_jobhistory   
   {   [ @job_name = ] 'job_name' |   
     | [ @job_id = ] job_id }  
   [ , [ @oldest_date = ] oldest_date ]
```

Per the documentation, `'job_name'` is the name of the job for which to delete the history records. Either `job_id` or `job_name` must be specified, but both cannot be specified.

Comment: Thank you for your answer however, I mention `sp_purge_history` right at the begining on [my answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/235515/22336). `that trims the jobhistory not the table log`